# Как запустить цикл в цикле паралельно?

Tags: python-3.x

Как запустить цикл в цикле и сразу продолжить паралельно основной цикл?

```
while True:
     while True:
        print('loop2')
     print('loop1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно параллельно перебирать две сущности, например два списка или два генератора, то можно использовать функцию [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp).

Пример кода по ссылке выше:

```
a = ("John", "Charles", "Mike")
b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica")

x = zip(a, b)
for pair in x:
    print(pair)
```

На выходе:

```
("John", "Jenny"),
("Charles", "Christy")
("Mike", "Monica")
```

Если Вы всё же хотите запускать много подциклов в параллель, то Вам нужны потоки, как Вам уже и ответили...

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
     print("loop2")
     def loop1():
          print("loop1")
     loop1()
```